# Why do we need to downcast a variable even if the function will upcast it again right before returning?

Tags: c++, embedded, downcast

While reading a book about modern C++, I have seen a code snippet that confused me. The code has been written to set up PWM (16 bit Timer) for 8 bit AVR microcontroller. The code is like that:

```
class pwm_base : private util::noncopyable
  {
  public:
    typedef std::uint_fast16_t duty_type;

    pwm_base(const duty_type resol,
             const duty_type duty = 0U) : resolution(resol),
                                          counter   (0U),
                                          duty_cycle(duty),
                                          shadow    (duty) { }

    duty_type get_resolution() const { return resolution; }

    void set_duty(const duty_type duty)
    {
      // Set a new duty cycle in the shadow register.
      mcal::irq::disable_all();

      shadow = static_cast<std::uint_fast8_t>((std::min)(duty, get_resolution())); // ???? (1)

      mcal::irq::enable_all();
    }

    duty_type get_duty() const
    {
      // Retrieve the duty cycle.
      mcal::irq::disable_all();

      const volatile std::uint_fast8_t the_duty = duty_cycle; // ???? (2)

      mcal::irq::enable_all();

      return the_duty;
    }

    virtual void service() = 0;

  protected:
    const duty_type resolution;
          duty_type counter;
          duty_type duty_cycle;
          duty_type shadow;
  };
```

I have problems with lines indicated by `????`. It is clearly seen that both, `shadow` and `duty_cycle` have been defined as `uint_fast16_t`. So, it means that they have to be at least 16 bits. If it is the case, why does the author downcast the result of min method to `uint_fast8_t` instead of casting to `uint_fast16_t` at line `???? (1)` ? And also, why does at line `???? (2)` he downcast again the variable to `uint_fast8_t` even if the function return type is `uint_fast16_t`? Are these downcastings required? What are their purposes?

Comment: Only the author of the book can answer this question.

Comment: Strange, especially as values might be truncated depending of type...

Comment: Looks like an error to me

Comment: Yes, indeed it was very strange for me also. Additionally, author uses such a lot of casting that I forgot what I know about casting, as I don't know which one is required which one is optional.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a book that anyone should be reading... what's it called?

Comment: It is called "Realtime C++. Efficient object-oriented and template microcontroller programming. Christopher Kormanyos". Indeed I liked the book very much as it teaches you what you need for MCU programing using C++. But, I think he has some kind of love for casting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code seems severely over-engineered, which is always the biggest danger whenever you allow C++. The language tends to encourage making things needlessly complicated just for the heck of it, instead of utilizing the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

The hard requirements are: on the given hardware, the CPU works fastest with 8 bit types but the PWM register is 16 bits. Period.

Therefore any variable describing period or duty cycle needs to be *exactly* 16 bits. It doesn't make sense to declare it as `uint_fast16_t` because the corresponding hardware registers will always be exactly 16 bits, no more, no less.

In general the `uint_fast` types are only helpful if planning to port this to a 32 bit system somehow, but it is very unlikely that there will exist a 32 bit MCU with an identical PWM peripheral. Thus in this case `uint_fast` is just useless noise, because the code will never get ported.

The cast to `uint8_t` supposedly truncates the 16 bit value to the 8 least significant bits. If so, the cast is incorrect, it should never be `static_cast<std::uint_fast8_t>` but `static_cast<std::uint8_t>`. I'm otherwise not quite following what the code is supposed to do, update the duty cycle somewhere, I would assume.

Furthermore, disabling the interrupt mask as a re-entrancy protection feature probably doesn't make sense, as this can cause unexpected timing problems. If this class is to be used from inside an ISR then another protection mechanism might be more suitable, such as a semaphore or atomic access/inline asm. PWM in particular is picky with when/how you change the duty cycle, or you might get glitches.

Overall, I would strongly recommend not to use C++ on an ancient, severely resource-confined 8 bit microcontroller. Or to use ancient 8 bit microcontrollers instead of ARM when learning embedded systems, 8-bitters are much harder to program in C (or C++) than 32-bitters.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation and your recommendation. So, at least I understood that the problem is in the code.

Comment: @BHOS Perhaps the PWM hardware on this part supports an 8 bit resolution mode? I'm not quite sure why anyone would ever want to use that though; every 8-bitter I've ever worked with supported 16 bit PWM.

Comment: On AVR disabling interrupts is the recommended (if not only) way of achieving atomicity for types >8 bits. Last time i checked it, this architecture did not support any kind of exclusive load/store and all the atomicity within its stdlib was done exactly this way.

Comment: @alagner Disabling the global interrupt mask is very clunky and never recommended, _especially_ not in library code, or the person who wrote the lib was incompetent. I've troubleshooted far too much microcontroller code where some driver sneakily did just that and then screwed up all real-time in the whole application. Disabling the specific interrupt might be ok. Interrupts aren't interruptible though, so if the purpose for re-entrancy is to communicate with an ISR, you can use a "poor man's semaphore" as described here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102.

Comment: @Lundin `Disabling the global interrupt mask is very clunky and never recommended`, hard to disagree, but tell that to chip vendors and authors of its datasheet. ;) I haven't taken that from the top of my head.

Comment: @alagner Chip vendors are notoriously bad at writing software. It's some on-going competition between them - who's got the least competent programmers.

Comment: There are however worse 8-bitters than AVR for C or C++ (the architectures that predated either language).  Of any 8 bit architecture AVR is probably the least C or C++-hostile.  Love it or hate it, the whole Arduino ecosystem  is based on C++ and largely on AVR devices.

Comment: @Clifford Well yes everything ever made is better than 8051... And what platforms a hobbyist/student project uses isn't very relevant in a discussion regarding embedded systems in a professional context. Other than that, I find AVR quite similar to HC08 and STM8, at least on the assembler level. It's all obsolete technology though.